# Php explode data to array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I fund few posts to explode data as array but mine is bit specific because the data has 2 parts

I have this

```
title=Title1|link=Link1
title=Title2|link=Link2
```

and result I need is this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title1
            [link] => Link1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title2
            [link] => Link2

        )

)
```

data is coming from texarea separated by \n  so the data you see is actual data

thank you!

Comment: wait, why two title vars? please explain further. how can there be two values in one title variable?

Comment: Paste some actual code that you have. Thanks

Comment: @Hoseph @ Vasanthan.R.P is the actual code , data is coming from textarea separated by \n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm more a fan of `explode()` than `preg_match()` when you don't actually need regular expressions.

```
<?php

$text="title=Title1|link=Link1\ntitle=Title2|link=Link2";

$result=array();
$count=0;

// line by line...
foreach (explode("\n", $text) as $line) {
  // variable by variable...
  foreach (explode("|", $line) as $vars) {
    // separate LHS from RHS.
    $parts=explode("=", $vars);
    $result[$count][$parts[0]]=$parts[1];
  }
  $count++;
}

print_r($result);

?>
```

Don't forget to add code to handle lines that don't match the pattern you expect.  Input validation is important.

Comment: Nice to see comments in code.  And +1 for code that actually *works* and also returns precisely the output that the OP asked for.

Comment: actually much cleaner and sorted , thank you! will come handy

Comment: I just had to change the answer to yours , this is what I call clean coding, many thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome.  Kudos to @Czechnology though for coming up with a one-liner that got you 90% of the way!

Comment: Kudos to all that helped me within seconds after brainstorming for 2h

Answer (score 6):

```
preg_match_all('~^title=(.+)\|link=(.+)$~m', $text, $reg, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

`print_r($reg)` produces

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => title=Title1|link=Link1
            [1] => Title1
            [2] => Link1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => title=Title2|link=Link2
            [1] => Title2
            [2] => Link2
        )

)
```

I'm sure you can easily modify that to fit your required schema.

Comment: sorry but I don't see how it produces and array i set $text as the data I have and print_r  outputs 1

Comment: I agree that `preg_match` may be a very good option for this.

Comment: ok can you please use example I gave , for example ,, $data ="title=Title1|link=Link1\ntitle=Title2|link=Link2";

Comment: @Benn, the output array is in `$reg`. See `print_r($reg)` (or - if you need to capture the output of print_r, use `$str = print_r($reg, true)`).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this, it's a bit verbose but you should be able to use it as the basis for something more elegant.

```
<?
$result=array();

foreach ($line in $iterable_variable_with_one_line_per_iteration){
    $subresult=array();
    foreach ($kv_pair in explode($line,"|")){
          $kv_pair_2 = explode($kv_pair,"=");
          $subresult[kv_pair_2[0]]=$kv_pair_2[1];
    }
    array_push($result,$subresult);
}
?>
```